# XML representation of nested multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, json, xml

XML allows having children with the same name while properties in JSON object notation should have unique names. [RFC 4627 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.2)

I have the following issue;

XML sample I:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <users>
    <user>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>John Doe</name>
    </user>
    <user>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Brian Matovu</name>
    </user>
  </users>
</document>
```

JSON equivalent I:

```
{
  "users": {
    "user": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Brian Matovu"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

XML sample II:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <users>
    <user>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>John Doe</name>
    </user>
  </users>
</document>
```

JSON equivalent II:

```
{
  "document": {
    "users": {
      "user": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John Doe"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JSON equivalent II*:

```
{
  "document": {
    "users": {
      "user": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "John Doe"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I encode my XML to translate to **JSON equivalent II*** whenever I have 1 user!

Comment: What are you using to translate XML into JSON?

Comment: Am using my Laravel package (https://github.com/mtvbrianking/laravel-xml) but this online converter (https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson) has exactly the same behavior.

Comment: Well, looking at the documentation, I'm not sure you can. You can add an empty child `<user/>` but that gives you an array with an empty second value.

Comment: Yah tried that but it appends an empty array. 